# CakePHP Getting form value and checking into database if exists

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, model, controller

i want to get data from post then check it in another model
here's my model

```
table Goods :
id,
goods_plu

table Transaction :
id,
transaction_plu
```

in case i want to add transaction and get the plu then check if

```
if($trans_plu == $goods_plu )
```

if trans_plu are exists in Goods Table
data will save in database

here's my form

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Transaction'); ?>
   <input type="text" name="trans_plu">
   <?php echo $this->Form->button('Save'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

thanks advance!

Comment: Sorry, but I got quite confused reading your question. When using CakePHP you should follow its standards/conventions, ie. `Transaction` should be `Transactions`, etc. It seems like you have `transaction_plu` in your table and `trans_plu` in your form.

Comment: And I don't know specifically, what you are asking. You need to reformulate your question with a little bit more code, before someone can suggest an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do the checking in TransactionsController, and you can find out if the trans_plu is in goods table.

```
class TransactionsController extends AppController{
   public $uses = array('Transaction', 'Goods');
   public function add(){
      if(!empty($this->data){
         $goodsCount = $this->Goods->read('goods_plu', $this->data['Transaction']['trans_plu']);
         if(!is_null($goodsCount)){
            $this->Transaction->save($this->data);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Let me know how it goes